# Setting up an Ubuntu partition on a Mac

Tags: installation, dual-boot, partitioning, mac

Look, I'm trying to set up a Linux partition on my Macbook Pro. I did exactly like what everybody says:

1. I partitioned the hard drive,
2. Downloaded rEFit, and installed that.
3. Then, I burned Ubuntu to a disc, which I put into my laptop, and
   rebooted.

The rEFit boot loader came up, but without Linux; it had a windows option now.

Thinking maybe they just misclassified it, I clicked on that, which black-screened me. I rebooted. This time, rEFit didn't even come up; it just went straight to OS X. Every time after that, I can't get rEFit to come back. It won't come up.

I've re-downloaded it multiple times, but it doesn't seem to work. Anyone got a fix?

Answer (score 0):

Refit is only availabe when you installed multi os on mac.
So you should press option key to select dvd.